# IOS 6 How the User App will come to foreground After Successful Login In Native App of Twitter In Settings App?

Tags: objective-c

I have integrated Twitter In My App in IOS 6.

My working Code is here

```
-(IBAction)uploadPhotoToTwitter
{

  //IOS 6 Twitter Integration

  SLComposeViewController *composeController = [SLComposeViewController                                             composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
  [composeController setInitialText:@"ios 6 TESTING"];

  [composeController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cat.jpg"]];

  [composeController setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    NSString *output;

    switch (result) 
    {
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            output = @"Tweet cancelled.";
            break;
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            output = @"Tweet done. ios 6";
             break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  }];
  [self presentViewController:composeController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When I click `uploadToTwitter` Button.It Shows Twitter post page and sends image url to Twitter.
Fine Its working .

Now My question is If Click uploadToTwitter Button and before that I have not logged in Then It  Shows

[image]

When I click Settings ,Then It go to Twitter App of Settings Page. Then I Logged In to Twitter.Up to that No problem is there.Login Successful.Then
The question is After successful login,It is still in Twitter App Page.Not Coming back to Original App and My original App is Still in background.How my original App will come to Foreground programmatically?